# Add string to list using either AWK or SED?

Tags: sed, awk, gawk

Hi I want to be able to edit the list of name like this using either AWK or SED.

Sample input list file:

```
john
paul
rose
lily
```

Desired output:

```
I am john of earth;
I am paul of earth;
I am rose of earth;
I am lily of earth;
```

I want the semicolons at the end too. i don't want to use shell scripts of for loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/.*/I am & of earth;/' file.txt 
I am john of earth;
I am paul of earth;
I am rose of earth;
I am lily of earth;
```

Answer (score 5):

With `awk` you can use `print`:

```
awk '{ print "I am", $1, "of earth;" }' list
```

or `printf`:

```
awk '{ printf("I am %s of earth;\n", $1); }' list
```